# Can the IF statement be used instead of WHILE loop in this script?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

I'm learning JavaScript with the help of a number of books. In one of them I came up with a script that displays a couple of flags and then you click on them to randomly change them:

```
var myImages = new Array("usa.gif","canada.gif","jamaica.gif","mexico.gif");

function changeImg(that) {
        var newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);

        while (that.src.indexOf(myImages[newImgNumber]) != -1)
        {
            newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
        }

        that.src = myImages[newImgNumber];
        return false;
}
```

It has a while loop to make sure that when you click on a flag you don't end up with the same one.
The rest of the code in HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
    <img name="img0" src="usa.gif" border="0" onclick="return changeImg(this)" />
    <img name="img1" src="mexico.gif" border="0" onclick="return changeImg(this)" />
</body>
```

Now, my question is, if I use an IF statement instead of a while loop, apparently the code works the same. In this particular example why is the while loop used instead of IF?
Thanks.

Comment: There's a small chance that a single re-try will pick the same number again, so the `while` loop lets the function keep trying repeatedly.

Comment: You use "if" over while only when you are not expecting multiple outcomes.

Comment: Got it. Thanks everybody for your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `while` statement basically translates as "while the number I've chosen matches the index of the image already in the current image tag, continue". So while an `if` statement may work most of the time, it's possible that your random number generator could generate, say, the number `0` multiple times in a row when you click on `img0`. `while` ensures that eventually you'll get a new image.

Answer (score 3):

There's a random number involved; you could get the same random number twice in a row.

Checking once is insufficient–the next number generated could be the same.

Answer (score 1):

No because you could choose the same one twice in a row since you are using random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is to make a random shuffle. Try to read answers to that question:
[How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: OP's goal was to understand the JS code in the book, I think?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Evidently I'm new at coding and I'm just trying to understand the logic behind the statements by asking "what if  i used this instead of that".